# How to call didUpdateLocation in another viewcontroller class from custom location manager?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have the following custom location manager class, I have another view controller that has a map view, how do I use this location manager to update the map view's coordinate when the user moves? For some reason I cannot even call the `didUpdateLocations` function in my other view controller.

```
class CustomLocationManager:NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    static let shared = CustomLocationManager()
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    private override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    }

    func startTracking() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    }

    func stopTracking(){
        locationManager.stopUpdatingHeading()
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        for currentLocation in locations{
            print("\(index):\(currentLocation)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more than one way to achieve it.

### Delegation:

A simple handy one to do so is to create your *own* delegate!

So what you could do is:

```
protocol CustomLocationManagerDelegate: class {
    func customLocationManager(didUpdate locations: [CLLocation])
}

class CustomLocationManager:NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    static let shared = CustomLocationManager()

    // tip: it is better to declare `locationManager` as private, so you can only access it
    // from the manager...
    private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    // here is the delegate:
    weak var delegate: CustomLocationManagerDelegate?

    private override init()
    {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest}
    func startTracking()
    {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    }

    func stopTracking()
    {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingHeading()
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // calling the delegate method
        delegate?.customLocationManager(didUpdate: locations)
    }
}
```

Therefore, when using the `CustomLocationManager` in a view controller, just make sure to let it conforms to `CustomLocationManagerDelegate`; Example:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    // ...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        CustomLocationManager.shared.startTracking()
        CustomLocationManager.shared.delegate = self
    }
    // ...
}

extension MyViewController: CustomLocationManagerDelegate {
    func customLocationManager(didUpdate locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // here we go:
        for currentLocation in locations {
            print("\(index):\(currentLocation)")
        }
    }
}
```

### Closure:

Another way to achieve it is by declaring a closure in `CustomLocationManager`:

```
class CustomLocationManager:NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    static let shared = CustomLocationManager()

    // here is the closure
    var updatedLocations: (([CLLocation]) -> Void)?

    // tip: it is better to declare `locationManager` as private, so you can only access it
    // from the manager...
    private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    // here is the delegate:
    weak var delegate: CustomLocationManagerDelegate?

    private override init()
    {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest}
    func startTracking()
    {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    }

    func stopTracking()
    {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingHeading()
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // here we call it:
        updatedLocations?(locations)
    }
}
```

Therefore, in the view controller:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        CustomLocationManager.shared.startTracking()

        CustomLocationManager.shared.updatedLocations = { [weak self] locations in
            guard let unwarappedSelf = self else { return }
            // unwarappedSelf.blablabla

            for currentLocation in locations {
                print(currentLocation)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Keep in mind** if you are aiming to follow this approach: in order to avoid retain cycles, don't forget to use the `weak self` (capture list `[weak self]`) for the closure and use the unwrapped version of `self` (`unwarappedSelf`).

Comment: if you gonna send everything in protocol method `CustomLocationManagerDelegate ` , then why not directly conform to `CLLocationManagerDelegate `  inside the vc ? there should be a handy for making it easy

Comment: @Sh_Khan I think it better to deal with the manager delegate instead of `CLLocationManagerDelegate ` directly for the sake of *decoupling* the responsibilities. In addition, conforming to `CustomLocationManagerDelegate` means that there is *only* one *non-optional* method that has to be implemented; A ViewController should not care about handling the core location things, therefore, at this point we don't even need to import the `MapKit` in the view controller which seems to be logical :)

Comment: if so then send important things not `_ manager: CLLocationManager` as parameter will it be used ?

Comment: @frankcrest glad to help! I even also mentioned another simple way do it ;)